# Tkinter/TTK: How to determine if a ProgressBar reaches the maximum value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to make simple program that prints "done" to the console when a progress bar reaches the maximum value using ttk.

example:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk

root = Tk()

pb = tkinter.ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
pb.pack()
pb.start()

if pb['value'] == 100: #This isn't correct it's just an example.
    pb.stop()
    print("Done")

root.mainloop()
```

I'm currently using python 3.5.2, please try to avoid classes and objects, It's a bit hard for me to understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the value yourself by instructing a function to be called every 100ms or so, like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk

root = Tk()

pb = tkinter.ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
pb.pack()

def task():
    pb['value'] += 1
    if pb['value'] >= 99:
        print("Done")
    else:
        root.after(100, task) # Tell the mainloop to run "task()" again after 100ms

# Tell the mainloop to run "task()" after 100ms
root.after(100, task)

root.mainloop()
```

You typically don't start() the progressbar in determinate mode because you're supposed to update the value yourself. In indeterminate mode, the bar bounces back and forth to imply something is happening, which is why you need to start() it.

Comment: Aha, i was sure that the if statement was wrong. As i guessed it needs a function. Thanks for help.